# Pandas CSV : Check for each row if a column is empty

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to test for each row of a CSV file if some column are empty or not and change value of another column depending on that.

Here is what I have :

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True)
df['Multi-line'] = pd.Series(dtype=object)

for i, row in df.iterrows():
   if (row['Directory Number 1'] != np.NaN and row['Directory Number 2'] != np.NaN and row['Directory Number 3'] != np.NaN and row['Directory Number 4'] != np.NaN):
   df.at[i,'Multi-line'] = 'Yes'
```

If 2 "Directory Number X" or more are not empty, I want the "Multi-line" column to be "Yes" and if 1 or 0 "Directory Number X" are not empty then "Multi-line" should be "No".
Here is only one if just to show you how it looks but in my test sample, all Multi-line are set to "Yes", it seems like the problem is inside the If condition with the row value and the np.nan but I don't know how to check if a row value is empty or not..
Thanks for you help !

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you executed `df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True)`
before.

Then, to generate the new column, run:

```
df['Multi-line'] = df.apply(lambda row: 'Yes' if row.notna().sum() >= 2 else 'No', axis=1)
```

No need for explicit call to *iterrows*, as *apply* arranges just such
a loop, invoking the passed function for each row.

If your DataFrame has also **other** columns, especially when they can
have *NaN* values, then application of this lambda function should be
limited to just these 4 columns of interest.

In this case run:

```
cols = [ f'Directory Number {i}' for i in range(1, 5) ]
df['Multi-line'] = df[cols].apply(lambda row:
    'Yes' if row.notna().sum() >= 2 else 'No', axis=1)
```

Note also that a check like `if (row[s] != np.NaN):` as proposed
in the other solution is a bad approach, since *NaN* by definition
is not equal to another *NaN*, so you can't just compare two *NaN*s.

To check it try:

```
s = np.nan
s2 = np.nan
s != s2    # True
s == s2    # False
```

Then save any "true" string in *s*, running `s = 'xx'` and repeat:

```
s != s2    # True
s == s2    # False
```

with just the same result.

Comment: Still not working... all my "Multi-line" values are "Yes" even if there is only 1 Directory Number

Answer (score -1):

You can use a counter instead

```
df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.NaN, regex=True)
df['Multi-line'] = pd.Series(dtype=object)

cnt=0;
str = ['Directory Number 1','Directory Number 2','Directory Number 3','Directory Number 4'];

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for s in str:
        if (row[s] != np.NaN):
            cnt+=1;
    if (cnt>2):
        df.at[i,'Multi-line'] = 'Yes'
    else:
        df.at[i,'Multi-line'] = 'No'
    cnt=0;
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems easier like that but, the problem is that even if there is only 1 Directory number, the multi-value will still be "Yes", i just edited my post with some screenshots.